# Flutter: Is Google Map street view available in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Is Google Map street view available in Flutter? I know there is a plugin of Google Map but I couldn't find out if I can use Street view functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I am the owner of [flutter_google_street_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#web).

Flutter plugin [flutter_google_street_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view) provides street view and support web, Android and iOS.
Try it! The usage steps shown below.

Usage Steps:

1. Get an API key at https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/.
2. Specify your API key to your code.([Web](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#web), [Android](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#ios), [iOS](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_street_view#ios))
3. Create FlutterGoogleStreetView widget and the sample code show below.

   ```
   StreetViewController? streetViewController;

   FlutterGoogleStreetView(
     initPos: LatLng(25.0780892, 121.5753234),
     onStreetViewCreated: (StreetViewController controller) async {
      //save controller for late using
      streetViewController = controller;
      //change position by controller
      controller.setPosition(position: LatLng(37.769263, -122.450727))
    }
   )
   ```
4. Done and control **FlutterGoogleStreetView** by **streetViewController**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information– at the moment, it's not much more than a link. Please [edit] to add further details, such as an example, so that it will be more helpful for others in the future. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).